# ng-show when dict is not empty

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have tried:

```
ng-show="Object.keys(config.taggedNgramsDict).length !== 0"

ng-show="config.taggedNgramsDict !== {}"

ng-show="JSON.stringify(config.taggedNgramsDict) !== '{}'"
```

Here's what `config.taggedNgramsDict` looks like:

```
var add = function (word) {
    var final_booleans = []

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.number_terms; i++) {
        final_booleans.push(false)
    }

    $scope.config.taggedNgramsDict[word] = final_booleans
}
```

Note: add gets triggered every time a 'word' button is clicked in the frontend.

I have checked:

- `config.taggedNgramsDict` is the proper var name
- the Dict does become filled and emptied successfully, based on a function in `controller.js`
- '===', '==',''!==' and '!='

Comment: Are you clearing the value by doing  ``$scope.config.taggedNgramsDict={}`` ?

Comment: @Supercool. there is another func that has 'remove' which does delete items in the dict until it's empty. `config.taggedNgramsDict` is also initialised to an empty dict.

Comment: @nightOwl, Add a reference of `Object` in scope i.e. `$scope.Object = Object;`, then your code `ng-show="Object.keys(config.taggedNgramsDict).length !== 0"` should work

Comment: @Satpal I'll do that as soon as I can access my code (got some tech issues). Do you mean to add it at the beginning of `controller.js` or within the `add` func?

Comment: @nightOwl at the beginning of controller

Comment: @Satpal I was on holiday so didn't implement your suggested change. I just put that line it and it works - thank you! I have spent so much time trying to figure that one out. Could you explain why that fixes it?

Comment: Global objects are not available in view, unless added to scope

Comment: @Satpal perfect. That's worked for me - thanks!